# Calculate complex integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ix^2}d x=?$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How to calculate this elementary complex integral?  This is what we would encounter if we are studying the Green's function for Schroedinger's equation.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ix^2}d x=?$$
However, I think there  should be someone that posted similar question on Math SE, though I don't know how to search by equation.

Thank you very much if you can help me out! And I would be grateful if you can give more than one approach

---

P.S.: The equation $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-kt^2}d \sqrt{k}t=\sqrt{\pi}$ surely comes to my mind, but I don't know why it holds for $k\in\mathbb{C}$, because for me, the above integral is over real line, however, the question here is like integral on $y=e^{i \pi/4}x$  ( So I think it's the problem with my complex integral knowledge.)

I tried to rotate this integral path by $\pi/4$, but the two arcs at $R\rightarrow \infty$ seem not easy to handle either.

Comment: Hi Collin - Welcome to MSE - in order for the community to be able to assist you, you need to provide all working you have done so far. If you are looking for a starting point, please ask - but this site is not a 'homework for free' site.

Comment: Hint: This is all you need to solve:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\:dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: Assuming the jump into the complex domain is valid. I always do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to avoid complex funniness.

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ix^2}dx
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\cos(x^2)-i\sin(x^2))dx\\
&=2\int_{0}^\infty (\cos(x^2)-i\sin(x^2))dx\\
&=2\int_{0}^\infty \cos(x^2)dx-2i\int_{0}^\infty\sin(x^2))dx\\
\end{array}
$

and these are the
Fresnel integrals
$C(x)$ and $S(x)$
both of which approach
$\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8}
$
as $x \to \infty$.

Therefore the result is
$(1-i)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
$
as Claude Leibovici
got.

Comment: How did you avoid 'complexness' in this solution? :-)

Comment: By not letting $k$ be complex in. $\int e^{-kx^2} dx$ when the result had only been proven for real $k$.

Comment: Good way to avoid any further discussion about the complex ! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**
$$\int e^{-k x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2 \sqrt{k}}\,\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{k} x\right)$$
$$f(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-k x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{k}}$$
$$f(i)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{i}}=(1-i) \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}$$

Comment: Hi! I think it's because I'm not familiar with complex integral; so how can you guys play so freely on the $\mathbb{C}$ plane, without worrying much? The very reason I ask this is because I don't know why your second equation holds for k being a complex number. I tried to rotate this integral path by $\pi/4$ on the complex plane,  but the two arcs at $|x|\rightarrow \infty$ seem not trying to vanish.

Comment: @Collin, The reasoning behind this 'extrapolation' is that $f$ defines a holomorphic function on the right half-plane $H=\{k:\operatorname{Re}(k) > 0\}$ and a continuous function on $\overline{H}\setminus\{0\} = \{k : \operatorname{Re}(k) \geq 0, k \neq 0 \}$. Now, in view of *identity theorem*, if you can identify another holomorphic function $g$ on $H$ such that $f = g$ on $(0,\infty)$, then $f = g$ on all of $H$ as well. We can check that this argument works with $g(k)=\sqrt{\pi/k}$, and so, $f = g$ on $H$ by identity theorem and on all of $\overline{H}\setminus\{0\}$ by continuity.

Comment: @SangchulLee  Hi!  So this is the material covered by complex analysis?   I have encountered many times similar problems when doing complex integral. As a physicist, complex analysis is only usually covered by Math-physics course within a chapter.

Comment: See my answer that purposely avoids this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-kx^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\left(x\sqrt k\right)^2}dx$$
Use the $u$-substution $u=x\sqrt k$ and this transforms the integral into the form given in DavidG's suggestion. Can you take it from here?